# Query to select category ids, in which at least all subcategory ids are present. (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `#table1` (subCatId) and `#table2` (categoryId, subCatId).

**#table1**:

```
subCatId
---------
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

**#table2**:

```
categoryId   subCatId
---------------------
    1            1
    1            2
    1            3
    2            1
    2            2
    2            3
    2            4
    2            5
    3            1
    3            2
    3            5
    3            4
    4            1
    4            2
    4            3
    4            4
```

Output:

```
categoryId 
-----------
    2
    4
```

As at least all subCatId's (1, 2, 3, 4) are present in both categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t2.categoryId
from #table2 t2
group by t2.categoryId
having count(*) = (select count(*) from #table1);
```

This assumes that there is a proper foreign key relationship between `#table2.subCatId` and `#table1.subCatId` and that there are no duplicates.
If these were not the case, the more general solution would be:

```
select t2.categoryId
from #table2 t2 join
     #table1 t1
     on t2.subCatId = t1.subCatId  -- filter to be sure only matching subCatId are counted
group by t2.categoryId
having count(distinct t2.subCatId) = (select count(*) from #table1);
```